# Can some give me good jQuery lightbox plugin which has zoomin and zoomout function for larger images?

Tags: jquery, lightbox, zooming

Can some give me good jQuery lightbox plugin which has zoomin and zoomout function for larger images?

Lets say my original image has resolution of 1000px x 700px.

I don't want to load the whole image. So i want to load the image in low height and width( say 500px x 350px) when the user click thumbnail.

If the user want larger image then he/she can load full image using zoomin function.

Is there any jQuery lightbox plugin available which does this job? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fancybox 2 has the ability to further zoom your picture.
See the Button helper example, there you can find Toggle Size button...

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/